# iOS App crashes when started in Release Mode, but not when in Debug Mode

Tags: ios, xcode, crash

When trying to launch my Application not using Xcode, the App crashes upon opening a specific ViewController. I've checked the Device Logs but I can't figure out what exactly caused the problem.

```
Incident Identifier: 20BC06E7-31B0-4C0D-B563-9D28FCE7A51D
CrashReporter Key:   17799fa3afc4ff5354281302e5f0d5909740c60b
Hardware Model:      iPhone9,3
Process:             Wizy [7883]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/8471B027-87B4-408C-802D-526BC2B73E8A/Wizy.app/Wizy
Identifier:          Wizypay.Wizy
Version:             3 (1.0.1)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           Wizypay.Wizy [3810]


Date/Time:           2018-06-26 17:53:40.5443 +0200
Launch Time:         2018-06-26 17:53:37.7096 +0200
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.4 (15F79)
Baseband Version:    2.03.12
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1831aad8c __exceptionPreprocess + 228
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1823645ec objc_exception_throw + 55
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1831aac6c +[NSException raise:format:] + 115
3   UIKit                           0x18d58b5fc UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 371
4   UIKit                           0x18d58b8b0 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1063
5   UIKit                           0x18d58b470 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 311
6   UIKit                           0x18d1e5be4 -[UIView initWithCoder:] + 647
7   UIKit                           0x18d58b738 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 687
8   UIKit                           0x18d58b470 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 311
9   UIKit                           0x18d429c94 -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 187
10  UIKit                           0x18d58b738 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 687
11  UIKit                           0x18d58b8b0 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1063
12  UIKit                           0x18d58b470 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 311
13  UIKit                           0x18d428fe4 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1163
14  UIKit                           0x18d25aaa8 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 371
15  UIKit                           0x18ce9e074 -[UIViewController loadView] + 175
16  UIKit                           0x18cdc2b14 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 171
17  UIKit                           0x18cdc2a50 -[UIViewController view] + 27
18  UIKit                           0x18d96c0f4 __67-[UIStoryboardEmbedSegueTemplate newDefaultPerformHandlerForSegue:]_block_invoke + 175
19  UIKit                           0x18d742af4 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _performWithDestinationViewController:sender:] + 291
20  UIKit                           0x18d7429a0 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 91
21  UIKit                           0x18d742c6c -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate perform:] + 159
22  UIKit                           0x18cdc2cb4 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 587
23  UIKit                           0x18cdc2a50 -[UIViewController view] + 27
24  UIKit                           0x18ce44620 -[UINavigationController preferredContentSize] + 167
25  UIKit                           0x18d006f10 -[UIPresentationController preferredContentSizeDidChangeForChildContentContainer:] + 67
26  UIKit                           0x18d23ede4 __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke + 139
27  UIKit                           0x18d19e884 _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 295
28  UIKit                           0x18d194958 _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 383
29  UIKit                           0x18d07951c _afterCACommitHandler + 131
30  CoreFoundation                  0x183152910 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 31
31  CoreFoundation                  0x183150238 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 411
32  CoreFoundation                  0x183150884 __CFRunLoopRun + 1435
33  CoreFoundation                  0x183070da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 551
34  GraphicsServices                0x185055020 GSEventRunModal + 99
35  UIKit                           0x18d08d758 UIApplicationMain + 235
36  Wizy                            0x100a45d70 0x1009e4000 + 400752
37  libdyld.dylib                   0x182b01fc0 start + 3
```

I tried changing the optimisation level in the build settings because someone suggested to do so, but no luck.

I hope someone can help me, I'm under time pressure!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: They suggested to change the optimization level to none so that you could then place breakpoints in your code and debug it.

Comment: So after changing that, the app is supposed to act the same way it does when launching it without xcode? I‘m asking because that wasn‘t the case when I ran it after changing the setting. Also, I recall that in Debug mode the optimisation was set to none anyway. Could you please explain what exactly the purpose of changing that setting is?

Comment: What code signing settings are you using when building for Release?  Are you using an In House distribution profile?

Comment: I haven't changed any settings, which ones exactly are of interest?

Comment: The view controller is already added to the release target?

Comment: Your storyboard/nib can't be decoded or found. Try clean and building. Unless you changed something specific, release shouldn't behave differently.

Comment: Cleaning and rebuilding didn‘t help. How do you know that my storyboard couldn‘t be decoded or found?

Comment: Its evident from the stack trace that either the storyboard/nib can't be found or decoded. `0x18d58b470 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 311` right after this call, the OS failed to decode value for that specific key and it raised an exception. Now, do you have different targets for debug and release? Having one target and only modifying the scheme shouldn't have this effect unless you modified something else like adding/removing files improperly before releasing. But, if you have multiple targets, make sure the storyboard or view controller has been added to your release target properly.